# Get and Add WHERE clause in SQL Query Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-parser

I am coding in Python. I have query like this:

```
SELECT device_os, count(*) FROM warehouse WHERE device_year <= 2016 GROUP BY device_os;
```

Now, I have some additional filters which are coming dynamically from the user. For example,

```
device_id IN (15, 85, 65) OR device_model in ('MAX', 'SHARP', 'AD')
```

I have these extra conditions which I want to apply to the query. So, the final query should become:

```
SELECT device_os, count(*) FROM warehouse WHERE device_year <= 2016 AND (device_id IN (15, 85, 65) OR device_model in ('MAX', 'SHARP', 'AD')) GROUP BY device_os;
```

I have searched about `sqlparse` but has not been successful. How can I make it look like what I want?

Comment: You need to clarify the roadblock here, it's not clear why you can't just use the final query? ex. input sanitization, string formatting, etc.

Comment: @talfreds because the basic query is already saved somewhere, and I need to add extra filters in where clause which are coming dynamically. It is assured that the user does not enter any malicious input. The user does not have a direct control to the database.

Comment: I think you have the options of parsing the user text (or making it, `field` + `list of values` rather than an entire expression, then it should be easy), or using a limited user that only has `SELECT ON db.warehouse` privs (is that restricted enough?).

Answer (score 2):

I made a library called [SQLGlot](https://github.com/tobymao/sqlglot) that makes this very easy.

```
import sqlglot
import sqlglot.expressions as exp

expression = sqlglot.parse_one("""
SELECT device_os, count(*) FROM warehouse WHERE device_year <= 2016 GROUP BY device_os
""") 

def transform(node):
    if isinstance(node, exp.Where):
        node.args["this"] = sqlglot.parse_one(f"({node.this.sql()}) AND device_model in (1,2,3)")
    return node

print(expression.transform(transform).sql(pretty=True))

# output
SELECT
  device_os,
  COUNT(*)
FROM warehouse
WHERE
  (device_year <= 2016)
  AND device_model IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY
  device_os
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the SQL as a template format string, then substutute the dynamically generated conditions into it.

```
sql_format = 'SELECT device_os, count(*) FROM warehouse WHERE device_year <= 2016 AND ({}) GROUP BY device_os;'
where_clause = 'device_id IN (%s, %s, %s) OR device_model in (%s, %s, %s)'
sql = sql_format.format(where_clause)
params = [15, 85, 65, 'MAX', 'SHARP', 'AD']
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

If you don't have any additional conditions, you can use

```
where_clause = '1=1'
```

This is a condition that's always true, so it doesn't change the result.